# Get size of resizable div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this resizable div using jQueryUI. I need to get it's size every time it is resized. My code is below:

```
$(".resizeable_div").on("resize", function(event, ui) {
    var h = $("#h").height();
    var w = $("#w").width();
});
```

The code above only gets the initial size of the div. Every time I resize the div the height and width doesn't change. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: as i remember, there is no `resize` event for div

Comment: there is, using jquery-ui using the codes above. the only problem I have is how to get the new size.

Comment: yep, I believe it only applies for `window` - [see here](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `resize` event is only raised by the `window`. You need to hook to the `stop` event in the `resizeable` plugin, and use the `ui` helper to get the size. Try this:

```
$(".resizeable_div").resizable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var w = ui.size.width;
        var h = ui.size.height;

        // do stuff...
    }
});
```

Comment: need to wait 5mins. :)